# After adding dismissible my stack layout widget become dead

Tags: flutter, dart

I added dismissible widget in my listview flutter app. after adding it my stack layout widget become a dead code and the list is not showing in my app.
it showing like 'instance of tasks'. but without dismissible the list is working fine. Please brother help me out from this problem. my code below-

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        _myAppBar(context),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height - 80,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = items[index];

                return Dismissible(
                  // Each Dismissible must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
                  // uniquely identify widgets.
                  key: new ObjectKey(items[index]),
                  // Provide a function that tells the app
                  // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    // Remove the item from the data source.
                    setState(() {
                      items.removeAt(index);
                    });

                    // Then show a snackbar.
                    Scaffold.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
                  },
                  // Show a red background as the item is swiped away.
                  background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                  child: ListTile(title: Text('$item')),
                );


                return Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  // The containers in the background
                  Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .width,
                        height: 80.0,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 14.0,
                            shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    todoType('${items[index].tasktype}'),
                                    Text(
                                      '${items[index].taskcustomername}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text(
                                          '${items[index].taskcustomeruserid}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontSize: 18.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          '${items[index].taskcustomermobileno}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontSize: 16.0),
                                        ),
                                        // ..........................dismiss


                                        //.................end dismiss


                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),


                ]);
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),);
}
```

i expect my list that i make for firestore.
but it's just showing -instance of 'tasks'

without dismissible the list is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the `Dismissible` and then returning the `Stack`, but the code after returning the `Dismissible` won't execute. You should put the `Stack` in the `Dismissible` child, replacing the `ListTile`.

Like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        _myAppBar(context),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height - 80,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = items[index];

                return Dismissible(
                  // Each Dismissible must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
                  // uniquely identify widgets.
                  key: new ObjectKey(items[index]),
                  // Provide a function that tells the app
                  // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    // Remove the item from the data source.
                    setState(() {
                      items.removeAt(index);
                    });

                    // Then show a snackbar.
                    Scaffold.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$item dismissed")));
                  },
                  // Show a red background as the item is swiped away.
                  background: Container(color: Colors.red),
                  child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                    // The containers in the background
                    Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery
                              .of(context)
                              .size
                              .width,
                          height: 80.0,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                            child: Material(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              elevation: 14.0,
                              shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      todoType('${items[index].tasktype}'),
                                      Text(
                                        '${items[index].taskcustomername}',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 20.0),
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            '${items[index].taskcustomeruserid}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            '${items[index].taskcustomermobileno}',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 16.0),
                                          ),
                                          // ..........................dismiss


                                          //.................end dismiss


                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),


                  ]),
                );

              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying ..    can you be more specific . I tried to replace the listtile with stack but its getting error.   How i can take the stack in my dismissible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are great bro .. Thanks for the help. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

In your Code you are returning both Dismissible and Stack Widget 
try to put Dismissible Widget in to Stack